# Find last populated row, copy and transpose values into column

Tags: excel, vba

When I try the following code it does everything right (i.e. finds the last row, copies and pastes) except it only pastes the first value from the row in the new table:

```
Sheets("x").Select
Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Copy
Sheets("y").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
```

How can I make it pull the full row range from B:I and paste in the new table instead of just the first value?

Much appreciation in advance for the help!

Comment: You're only copying a single cell on sheet x.  Did you want to copy the whole row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sheets("x").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Resize(1,8).Copy
Sheets("y").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True
```

or avoiding copy/paste:

```
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Sheets("x").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Resize(1, 8)

Sheets("y").Range("A1").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, 1).Value = _
                             Application.Transpose(rng.Value)
```